# Quero subtrair elementos de um array em JS, mas que me retorne vários resultados

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo subtrair valores de um *array* em JavaScript, mas não é uma subtração de um valor de um determinado *array* por outro.

Quero fazer o seguinte: tenho um *array* qualquer que me trás valores reais do meu banco. Nesse caso vou colocar um pra exemplificar:

```
var arrayExemplo = [2, 5, 9, 10, 15];
```

Quero subtrair

- o elemento 5 pelo elemento 2
- o elemento 9 pelo elemento 5
- o elemento 10 pelo elemento 9
- o elemento 15 pelo elemento 10

Quero que meu resultado saia

```
[3, 4, 1, 5]
```

Como posso fazer?

Comment: Não é uma tarefa complexa, o que esteve tentando? Podemos te ajudar nas partes que tem dúvida ou não conseguiu

Answer (score 1):

Basta utilizarmos um `for` que percorre o tamanho do vetor e subtrairmos a posição i+1 pela posição i

```js
var arrayExemplo = [2, 5, 9, 10, 15];
var novoArray = [];
for(i = 0; i < arrayExemplo.length-1; i++)
{
  novoArray[i] = arrayExemplo[i+1]- arrayExemplo[i];
  console.log(novoArray[i]);
}
```

```html
<h4>ArrayExemplo = [2, 5, 9, 10, 15]<h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayResultado = [arrayExemplo[1] - arrayExemplo[0],arrayExemplo[2]-arrayExemplo[1],arrayExemplo[3]-arrayExemplo[2],arrayExemplo[4]-arrayExemplo[3]];
```

Comment: Não fui eu que dei o `-1` mas a tua solução é demasiado adaptada ao exemplo e não vai funcionar se a array inicial tiver mais elementos, ou menos elementos.

Comment: Essa não é uma resposta adequada Helder, o usuário ficará limitado apenas a esse vetor. (também não dei -1)

Comment: Sei que sim, mas a duvida pode ser, apenas, se se pode fazer subtracções com elementos de um array dentro de um outro array. Ele dá o exemplo em subtrai (i+1 - i) mas se ele quiser fazer subtracções aleatória?

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
var arrayExemplo = [2, 5, 9, 10, 15];

function subtrair(arr) {
  return arr.reduceRight((res, el, i, arr) => {
    return (i == 0) ? res : res.concat(el - arr[i - 1]);
  }, []).reverse();
}

var resultado = subtrair(arrayExemplo);
console.log(resultado);
```

Usando o `reduceRight` iteras do fim da array inicial.

Answer (score 0):

Faça um for, e não se esqueça de colocar uma verificação de índice:

```
var arrayExemplo = [2, 5, 9, 10, 15];
var resultado = [];
for (i = 0; i < arrayExemplo.length - 1; i++) {
    resultado[i] = arrayExemplo[i + 1]- arrayExemplo[i];
}
```

Comment: Não é necessário um if, basta percorrermos o for com uma posição a menos do vetor.

Comment: Verdade, editado, obrigado @Bsalvo